# Tkinter to display multiple randomly selected images in single window

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import random

from Tkinter import Label,Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog


path = '/Users/InNov8/Desktop/broadcast/test'

# All images in the directory get stored in this list
images = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        if '.jpg' in file.lower() or '.gif' in file.lower() or '.png' in file.lower():
            images.append(file)


# random number of images to pick from within a range
random_max = random.randrange(2, 3)
print random_max

# list to hold the selected images
selection = []
counter = 0
while counter < random_max:
    index = random.randrange(0, len(images))
    selection.append(images[index])
    print images[index]
    images.pop(index)
    counter +=1 

print selection


# display the selected images in a Tkinter window
root = Tk()

for s in selection:
    im = Image.open(s)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    myvar=Label(root,image = tkimage)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want to randomly pick images from a folder and display them in a Tkinter window. If I like the pictures, I'll add a "go" button to use them, otherwise I'll add a "pick again" button to reselect.

Since the number of selected images always varies, I am trying to figure out a way to be dynamic which is why I setup the loop at the end. Of course this doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "Of course this doesn't work" - why's that? Crashes (what's the exception)? Nothing pops up? You don't have any images on your computer? You forgot to install python? Some more details would help narrow this down much faster

Answer (score 1):

figured out that my original code actually works but the issue was an inability to scroll.

Here's the final code with scrollbars added:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import random

from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkFileDialog


path = '/Users/InNov8/Desktop/broadcast/test'

images = []

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    # for subdirname in dirnames:
        # print os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        if '.jpg' in file.lower() or '.gif' in file.lower() or '.png' in file.lower():
            images.append(file)


random_max = random.randrange(2, 5)
print random_max

selection = []
counter = 0
while counter < random_max:
    index = random.randrange(0, len(images))
    selection.append(images[index])
    print images[index]
    images.pop(index)
    counter +=1 



print selection


## Main window
root = Tk()
## Grid sizing behavior in window
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
## Canvas
cnv = Canvas(root)
cnv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
## Scrollbars for canvas
hScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=cnv.xview)
hScroll.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
vScroll = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL, command=cnv.yview)
vScroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
cnv.configure(xscrollcommand=hScroll.set, yscrollcommand=vScroll.set)
## Frame in canvas
frm = Frame(cnv)
## This puts the frame in the canvas's scrollable zone
cnv.create_window(0, 0, window=frm, anchor='nw')
## Frame contents

for s in selection:
    im = Image.open(s)
    tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    myvar=Label(frm,image = tkimage)
    myvar.image = tkimage
    myvar.pack()

## Update display to get correct dimensions
frm.update_idletasks()
## Configure size of canvas's scrollable zone
cnv.configure(scrollregion=(0, 0, frm.winfo_width(), frm.winfo_height()))
## Go!


root.mainloop()
```